# Conditions bug in Adobe DTM rules

Tags: tags, adobe, web-analytics, adobe-analytics

I'm facing a strange matter about the Conditions for the Page-load rules, in the Adobe Dynamic Tag Manager.
I previously tested some "Domain" conditions, and the last was based on a single domain value.
Now, when I try to set new "Domain" conditions and I click "Add criteria", the UI  provides me that old test only, with no modification possibility.
This looks like a bug.
If not, where can I modify the previous Conditions set ?
I'd like to test a new Regex for a new Domain one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I'm not discounting the possibility of there being a bug in DTM (*Lord knows, I've found/submitted several bugs*), but more than likely if it is "read only" to you now, then someone else with admin permissions has probably lowered your user account permissions to not allow editing of rules.

Secondly, as far as the rule in general..

When you select `Rule Conditions > Criteria > "Domains"` and click "Add Criteria", it only shows a list of domains that you have defined in the main property config, and there is a checkbox next to each one listed, and you can only select one or more of them to match the current domain against, and it's an exact string comparison. DTM doesn't provide a way to do anything other than that, for the "Domains" Criteria, so you cannot do a regex match this way.

If you want to create a condition that matches current domain against a regex, then you can instead select the "Custom" option in the Criteria dropdown, and write your own (javascript syntax) logic in the code box there.

**Example:**

```
// only trigger if on www.mysite.com
if ( location.hostname.match(/^www\.mysite\.com$/i) ) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

**Note:** This is a simple example. Ultimately, you want to return `true` if you want the condition to allow the rule to trigger, or `false` if you want the condition to prevent the rule from triggering.

Comment: Very nice Crayon, this Custom criteria seems to suit me and I can leave the Domain one apart. Anyway I will investigate my DTM account capabilities for the future. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm gonna post another question regarding an advanced Data Element usage, and I expect your great help :-) Thx